# Error when trying to acess value of a form element in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome

I'm doing a chrome extension that when the button is pressed i get the current url and the value in the input field.

But i'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLButtonElement.myAlert
```

in the line:

```
var ip = document.getElementById('ip_dns').value;
```

How is the correct way to get and store this value?

Here is my code:

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DNS Teste</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
        IP DNS
        <input type="text" ip="ip_dns">
        <button id="btn">Teste</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function myAlert(){
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    var url = tab.url;
    console.log("url: "+ url);
  });
  var ip = document.getElementById('ip_dns').value;
  console.log("IP: "+ip);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', myAlert);
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have typo here:  <input type="text" ip="ip_dns">, maybe this is the issue? change it to  <input type="text" id="ip_dns">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works

```js
function myAlert(){
  // chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  //   var url = tab.url;
  //   console.log("url: "+ url);
  // });
  var ip = document.getElementById('ip_dns').value;
  console.log("IP: "+ip);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', myAlert);
});
```

```html
<form>
  IP DNS
  <input type="text" id="ip_dns">
  <button id="btn">Teste</button>
</form>
```